# Discrete math problems

Tags: discrete-mathematics, soft-question, big-list

I am a high school student interested in thinking about math. I don't know a lot of high-powered math (I only know up to calculus), instead I focus on discrete topics related to math Olympiads (combinatorics, number theory, geometry etc). Olympiad problems typically take 2-3 hours to solve. I want to start thinking about interesting problems over extended periods of time.

So I am wondering where I can find a bank of problems that satisfy the following criteria: they are simply stated, related to discrete topics (not graduate level math please), and are difficult enough that they cannot be solved in a day, but not as difficult as full fledged research problems. I am not talking about open problems nessecarily; I don't want to think about something like the Collatz conjecture, since that is too difficult as its been open for a long time.

I am sorry if I'm not being clear, but I dont know what more specifics I can give. Maybe someone can help me narrow down what I'm actually asking?

Comment: Are there any odd perfect numbers?

Comment: @Eoin Also, how many even perfect numbers exist? Also, how many twin primes are there?

Comment: You may find [this book](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=1MTcYrbTdsUC&printsec=frontcover&dq=David+Wells+book&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KGNYVLGhGpD_8QXBloKYCA&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAw) interesting.

Comment: Please solve this one, it drives me nuts: Let $X$ be a finite set, and $\mathcal{F}$ a collection of subsets of $X$ such that if $A$ and $B$ are elements of $\mathcal{F}$ then $A\cup B$ is in $\mathcal{F}$.  Show that there is an element $x\in X$ that is in at least half the elements of $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: You could go through some questions on this very site.

Comment: @Callus: Why don't you post this question?

Comment: Why is there such a systematic attempt to discourage interest in mathematics?

Answer (score 1):

You could go to different university course pages and look for their undergraduate discrete math course.
They are generally accessible to the public.

For exmaple:

http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs103/

http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~simon/TEACH/DISCRETE/

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-spring-2010/index.htm

And there are plenty more, have fun!